# Latex cannot find the bibliography items, why?

Tags: bibliographies, multibib

I have been trying to make multibib work for several hours, but it does not read or print the bibliography entries. What may be going wrong here? Should it be executed on the commmand line separately, instead of a gui (text editor)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,german,american]{article}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{J}{\normalsize{Journal publications}\vspace*{0truemm}}
\newcites{C}{\normalsize{Conference publications}\vspace*{0truemm}}
\newcites{R}{\normalsize{General publications}\vspace*{0truemm}}

\begin{document}

x \citeJ{paper1} \citeC{paper1} 
y \citeR{paper2} \citeR{paper2} 
z \citeJ{paper3} \citeC{paper3}

\bibliographystyleR{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyR{articles}

\bibliographystyleJ{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyJ{articles}

\bibliographystyleC{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyC{articles}
\end{document}
```

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples

Comment: I cannot produce the template_multibib.pdf result here either with the moderncv class. Is it me or the multibib package?

Comment: These are both multibib problems, one with the article class, the other with the modern cv class.

Comment: how do you do that with TeXnicCenter?

Answer (score 3):

According to section 1.2 of the [multibib package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibib) documentation, an additional `aux` file is generated for each bibliography created via `\newcites`. You need to run `bibtex` on these additional aux files. With your example code, three `.aux` files are created when you run LaTeX: `C.aux`, `J.aux`, and `R.aux` (as well as the usual `\jobname.aux`, of course).

Each one of these additional aux files needs to be BibTeX'ed separately. I would imagine that most IDEs are not set up to deal with this; instead, they (the IDEs) will direct bibtex at `\jobname.aux`, and hence no bibliography-related output will be produced. To process the additional aux files properly, then, you could open a command window, switch to the directory where the files are located, and issue the commands

```
bibtex C
bibtex J
bibtex R
```

Then, run LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes.

If you have a Unix-based system, the documentation suggests the following bash script to automate this process:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.aux ; do
  bibtex `basename $file .aux`
done
```

You could do the same in tcsh.

```
#!/bin/tcsh
foreach x (*.aux)
  bibtex `basename $x`
end
#
```

Comment: IDEs give errors when you try to execute .bib files. In which order should the executions from the terminal be?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by executing a `.bib` file. After running (pdf)latex you should do bibtex \`basename whatever.aux\` for every `.aux` file that is generated. Then run (pdf)latex again, more than once if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, the aux files.